# CSS transition working in chrome but not safari

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Have a simple button within a div(pa-search-style) in my header that is supposed to reveal a dropdown menu containing a multi-category search form.

Here is the code that I currently have implemented that appears to be working with chrome but not safari.

```
#pa-search-style  {
    --size-pa:100px;
    max-height: var(--size-pa);
    overflow:hidden;    
    -webkit-transition: max-height 500ms cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.28);
}
#pa-search-style:focus-within  {
    --size-pa:450px;
}
```

Such a simple issue and yet my endless googling returned nothing. I am now ready for one of you to make me feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just change the variable, re-apply it.

```
#pa-search-style:focus-within  {
    --size-pa:450px;
    max-height: var(--size-pa);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jon! I tried to add this code but still getting the same "no result" from Safari

Comment: Try without the webkit prefix and ditching the variable for debugging purposes (or even ditching the transition entirely).

Comment: So odd, even without the webkit prefix and variable I still get no response from safari. Also removed the transition entirely got the same result. Chrome seems to behave as expected.